# FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estoy tratando de acceder a una vista con un botón, literalmente he copiado y pegado el código desde un proyecto mío en el que funciona normal, y he probado con scaffold y sale el mismo error solo dentro de este proyecto.

Este es mi controlador que contiene el metodo que redirige a la vista de agregar registros, que en este caso es la que quiero ir.

```
namespace RentAcarNewP.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        public readonly ApplicationDbContext Context;
        public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext Context) {
            this.Context = Context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Carros> ListCarros = this.Context.Carros;
            return View(ListCarros);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Agregar()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Agregar(Carros carro)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                this.Context.Carros.Add(carro);
                this.Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la vista que contiene el botón que me redirige a la vista para agregar registros (a esta si puedo accesar normalmente)

```
@model IEnumerable<RentAcarNewP.Models.Carros> 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Admin";
    Layout = "_Layout2";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Lista de libros</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn btn-success d-block" asp-action="Agregar" asp-controller="Admin">Agregar registro</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Marca)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Modelo)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Placa)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Tipodecombustible)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Descripcion)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Estado)</td>
                        <td>Acciones</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Id</td>
                        <td>@item.Marca</td>
                        <td>@item.Modelo</td>
                        <td>@item.Placa</td>
                        <td>@item.Tipodecombustible</td>
                        <td>@item.Descripcion</td>
                        <td>@item.Estado</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success d-block">Editar</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success d-block">Borrar</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table="table">

        }
        else
        { 
            <h4>No hay regisros</h4>
        }



    </div>

</div>
```

Esta es la vista que contiene a la que quiero ir con el botón.

```
@model RentAcarNewP.Models.Carros
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Agregar";
    Layout = "_Layout2";
}
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Agregar</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <form method="post" asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Marca" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Marca" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Marca" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Modelo" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Modelo" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Modelo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Placa" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Placa" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Placa" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Tipodecombustible" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Tipodecombustible" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Tipodecombustible" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Descripcion" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Descripcion" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Descripcion" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Estado" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Estado" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Estado" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
      </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi modelo

```
namespace RentAcarNewP.Models
{
    public class Carros
    {
        [Key]        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="La marca es obligatoria")]
        [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage ="El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}")]
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El modelo es obligatorio")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}")]
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La placa es obligatoria")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}")]
        public string Placa { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El tipo de combustible es obligatorio")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}")]
        public int Tipodecombustible { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El estado es obligatoria")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}")]
        public int Estado { get; set; }

    }
}
```

me marca estas lineas de codigo dentro del error, pero no las entiendo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien cuando borro el código del form en la vista el codigo funciona y me redirige a la página, pero no logro hacer que funcione con el formulario.

Comment: ¿Existe `_Layout2.cshtml` en la ubicación mencionada?

Comment: Tu página espera un modelo Carros, sin embargo, cuando la cargas no pasas ningún modelo. Deberías pasarle el modelo Carros: return View(new Carros());

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en el modelo, el método correcto que debí utilizar en el caso de los strings era "Stringlength" y olvide setear un MinimunLength, después de setear el minimunLength y cambiar de método el error dejó de aparecer.

```
namespace RentAcarNewP.Models
{
    public class Carros
    {
        [Key]        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="La marca es obligatoria")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}", MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El modelo es obligatorio")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}", MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La placa es obligatoria")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}", MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Placa { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El tipo de combustible es obligatorio")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}", MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Tipodecombustible { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {2} y maximo {1}", MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El estado es obligatorio")]
        public string Estado { get; set; }

    }
}
```